# How to apply a piecewise function to a list?

Tags: list-manipulation, piecewise

I have created this code:

```
xn = {4, -4, 4, -4}
f[x_] = Piecewise[{{Sqrt[x], x >= 0}, {Sqrt[-x], x < 0}}]
f[xn]
```

With this code I would expect as a result:

> {2,2,2,2}

But that's not what I get.

Question 1 - Why don't I get the desired result?

Question 2 - How to get the desired result?

Comment: `f/@xn` or `SetAttributes[f, Listable]`...

Comment: What is the difference between f/@xn and f[xn]?

Comment: Why not use `Sqrt[Abs[x]]`?

Comment: "What's the difference" - in your notebook, highlight the `/@` and press F1, so that you can answer your own question.

Comment: Also note that using `Set`(`=`) does not scope the symbol `x` which may lead to trouble

Comment: @J.M. For some reaon Sqrt[Abs[x]] doesn't work, see: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/120577/strange-behavior-when-using-abs

Comment: Well, you didn't say that you were going to differentiate the blasted thing…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code shows two elementary misunderstandings. First, you do not understand the difference between [`Set`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html) and [`SetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html). Second, you do not understand what a [`Listable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Listable.html) function is. Yet both these concepts are fundamental to working with Mathematica.

An experienced Mathematica user would write your code as

```
xn = {4, -4, 4, -4};
f[x_] := Piecewise[{{Sqrt[x], x >= 0}, {Sqrt[-x], x < 0}}]
f /@ xn
```

without even having to think about it.