# Strange behavior of derivative when using Abs[]

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, piecewise

This code where I try to visualize Newton's Method on the function $f(x)=\sqrt{|x|}$ works fine when I define $f(x)$ piecewise. Then why doesn't it work when I define `f[x_] = Sqrt[Abs[x]]`?

This works:

```
Clear["Global`*"];
f[x_] = Piecewise[{{Sqrt[x], x >= 0}, {Sqrt[-x], x < 0}}];
guess = 5;
iter = 10;
xn = NestList[# - f[#]/f'[#] &, guess, iter] // N;
fn = f /@ xn;
dots = Transpose[{xn, fn}] /. {x_, y_} :> Sequence[{x, 0}, {x, y}];
Show[Plot[f[x], {x, -5, 5}], Graphics[Line[dots]]]
```

This doesn't work:

```
Clear["Global`*"];
f[x_] = Sqrt[Abs[x]];
guess = 5;
iter = 10;
xn = NestList[# - f[#]/f'[#] &, guess, iter] // N;
fn = f /@ xn;
dots = Transpose[{xn, fn}] /. {x_, y_} :> Sequence[{x, 0}, {x, y}];
Show[Plot[f[x], {x, -5, 5}], Graphics[Line[dots]]]
```

But why???

Comment: Do you know that |x| is not differentiable at x = 0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
f[x_] = Piecewise[{{Sqrt[x], x >= 0}, {Sqrt[-x], x < 0}}];
f'[x]
```

gives

$$ \begin{cases}
 -\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{-x}} & x<0 \\
 \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{x}} & x>0 \\
 \text{Indeterminate} & \text{True}
\end{cases}
$$

```
f[x_] = Sqrt[Abs[x]];
f'[x]
```

gives

$$
\frac{\text{Abs}'(x)}{2 \sqrt{\text{Abs}(x)}}
$$

So the second form doesn't evaluate the derivative in the way you think - it just substitutes e.g. `Abs'[guess]` but doesn't evaluate what that derivative is any further, and so gets stuck in a long loop.

Comment: Ah, great! Is there a way to use Abs[] as a function in the way I intended?

Comment: Yes - see the answer here in regards to complex numbers: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8188/simplifying-the-derivative-of-x